# Assigning heap objects to a std::map

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, dictionary

This crashes at runtime.

```
std::map<std::string, MyClass> myMap;
myValue = new MyClass();
myMap["myKey"] = *myValue;
```

I have 2 requirements:

1. That instances of MyClass are held on the heap (hence use of new);
2. That I be able to reference these via an associative array (hence use of std::Map).

Why can I not use the dereference operator succesfully in the example? How can I fulfill both at once?

PS. I'm using gcc.

Comment: why not `std::map<std::string, MyClass*>` ?

Comment: How is `myValue` defined ? Does `MyClass` have a proper copy constructor and assignment operator (that perform a deep copy if necessary) ?

Comment: The map should hold pointers to MyClass.
Your code creates a new instance and then inserts a copy into the map.
The copy in the map would actually be on the heap but it would not be safe to delete the instance in the map because the map handles the memory.
If you are managing deleting the items elsewhere, then just make the map take a pointer as mentioned above.

Comment: @Armen, I shall, if I can't follow this quickly to a logical conclusion (see my comments to Sander and Pete).

Comment: @Sander, No, I'm coming back to C++ for the first time in many years, so had forgotten about that. Presumably that is a requirement since the std containers always make copies?

Comment: @Pete, Can I do that? I thought it was unsafe to store pointers in std containers, hence std ptrs like shared_ptr?

Comment: @awoodland See question to Pete.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with storing bald pointers in std containers.
It could be unsafe if you are allocating with 'new' and storing directly in there.  If you wrap this in a class and define all the operations to manage the items correctly then its fine (e.g. boost::ptr_map).
In general, smart pointers reduce the risks associated with this type of use - but will clearly incur a performance penalty - YMMV...
It all boils down to who owns the pointers and is responsible for freeing the memory associated (and that may/may not be the heap, as you can always have pointers to stuff on the stack).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you lose the scope of `myValue` then it's a memory leak. So it's better to store the `MyClass*` in your map.

```
std::map<std::string, MyClass*> myMap;
myValue = new MyClass();
myMap["myKey"] = myValue;
```

In given example, also make sure you `delete` the element while erasing or removing from the `map<>`. You can use smart pointer (e.g. `boost::shared_ptr`) if you don't want to worry about memory management.

Also, from your given example I don't know why it should crash while dereferencing `*myClass`. Are you doing some weird stuff in copy constructor `MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)` ?

Comment: I haven't implemented a copy constructor. I assume this is the problem since std containers take copies. That answers my question of "why", so I've accepted your answer as it covers all bases.

Answer (score 5):

you could use this instead, using boost or tr1 shared_ptr:

```
std::map<std::string, shared_ptr< MyClass > > myMap;
myValue = shared_ptr< MyClass >( new MyClass() );
myMap["myKey"] = myValue;
```

no ownership issues, no memory leaks.

Comment: @Pete +1 indeed; I'm not sure the OP can use boost so stayed with tr1 which is more accessible

Answer (score 1):

your last line creates a new instance of `MyClass` in the map and invokes the assignment operator on that. I'm assuming your objects have some pointers in them and you get an error when trying to deallocate some memory twice.

Unlike Java, there are no implicit reference semantics in C++; if you want to store pointers, you need to use an `std::map<std::string, MyClass*>` and handle memory management accordingly, or, as stijn said, use some form of `shared_prt` for that.

Comment: "handle memory management accordingly", does that just mean calling delete as appropriate for each element? So it's safe to use a pointer in a std container, then?

Comment: It means that the objects to which you have pointers in the container need to be life-time-managed separately, yes. Other than that, I don't see problems with having pointers in standard containers. Still, code using smart pointers (not `std::auto_ptr`) or boost containers that will delete the objects for you is much easier to read (and write, but you'll read the code way more often than write it …) and to get right.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new object in line 2 and /copying/ it into the map. You are probably looking for a boost::ptr_map.